# how to do pagination complex array in cakephp rest-api?

Tags: php, json, rest, api, cakephp

CakePHP Rest-API pagination in an array of array. Like, containable model pagination in CakePHP for reducing API load.

Some existing code :

```
$this->request->data['page'];

$data = $this->Model1->find('all',array(
   'contain' => array('Model2'),
   'fields' => array(),
   'conditions' => array('Model1.status' => 1 ) 
));
```

Below API response and I want to paginate in ProductUser array because when lots of product load at one-time app will be hang. It's possible or any other way to reduce data load in CakePHP.

API Response :

```
"status": true,
"message": "Available devices!",
"data": [
  {  
  "id": "6",
  "name": "Television",
  "parent_id": "0",
  "image": "",
  "status": "1",
  "created": "2019-06-10 15:22:44",
  "modified": "2019-06-10 15:22:44",
  "ProductUser": [  //Paginate this array
    {
      "id": "1",
      "user_id": "17",
      "category_id": "6",
      "brand_id": "1",
      "product_id": "17",
      "date_of_purchase": "2019-06-22",
      "seller_id": "1",
      "warranty_year": "0",
      "warranty_month": "0",
      "warranty_end_date": null,
      "purchese_price": null,
      "bill_upload": "",
      "emi_year": "0",
      "emi_month": "0",
      "emi_start_date": null,
      "emi_end_date": null,
      "insurance_company_id": "0",
      "insurance_year": "0",
      "insurance_month": "0",
      "insurance_end_date": null,
      "created": "2019-06-22 14:13:01",
      "modified": "2019-06-22 14:17:07",
      "Product": {
        "id": "17",
        "category_id": "6",
        "brand_id": "1",
        "product_code": "Samsung LED TV 39 inch",
        "name": "Samsung LED TV 39 inch",
        "selling_price": "13000",
        "short_description": "Television",
        "image": "catalog\/sam39.jpg",
        "status": "1",
        "created": "2019-05-14 00:00:00",
        "modified": "2019-05-14 00:00:00"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "user_id": "17",
      "category_id": "6",
      "brand_id": "1",
      "product_id": "17",
      "date_of_purchase": "2019-06-22",
      "seller_id": "1",
      "warranty_year": "0",
      "warranty_month": "0",
      "warranty_end_date": null,
      "purchese_price": null,
      "bill_upload": "",
      "emi_year": "0",
      "emi_month": "0",
      "emi_start_date": null,
      "emi_end_date": null,
      "insurance_company_id": "0",
      "insurance_year": "0",
      "insurance_month": "0",
      "insurance_end_date": null,
      "created": "2019-06-22 14:13:01",
      "modified": "2019-06-22 14:17:07",
      "Product": {
        "id": "17",
        "category_id": "6",
        "brand_id": "1",
        "product_code": "Samsung LED TV 39 inch",
        "name": "Samsung LED TV 39 inch",
        "selling_price": "13000",
        "short_description": "Television",
        "image": "catalog\/sam39.jpg",
        "status": "1",
        "created": "2019-05-14 00:00:00",
        "modified": "2019-05-14 00:00:00"
      }
    }
  ]
}]
```

Comment: what does that `Model1` and `Model2` means. How you create relation with `ProductUser`.

Comment: @Fokrule hasMany Relationship